# jquery - convert a function into a variable

Tags: javascript, parameters, particles.js

I have few predefined parameters for [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) which is a free plugin to create animated backgrounds. User can change animation color and opacity. Later I want to add the particles.js parameters to a zip file using jsZip.

Problem: I am unable to store the parameters/function into a variable for the jsZip.

Here is my sample code for Particles.Js

```js
function particleBG2(particleColor, particleAlpha) {
  particlesJS("particles-js", {
    particles: {
      number: {
        value: 80,
        density: {
          enable: true,
          value_area: 800
        }
      },
      color: {
        value: particleColor
      },
      shape: {
        type: "circle",
        stroke: {
          width: 0
        },
        polygon: {
          nb_sides: 5
        },
        image: {
          src: "img/github.svg",
          width: 100,
          height: 100
        }
      },
      opacity: {
        value: particleAlpha,
        random: false,
        anim: {
          enable: false,
          speed: 1,
          opacity_min: 0.1,
          sync: false
        }
      },
      size: {
        value: 3,
        random: true,
        anim: {
          enable: false,
          speed: 40,
          size_min: 0.1,
          sync: false
        }
      },
      line_linked: {
        enable: true,
        distance: 150,
        color: particleColor,
        opacity: particleAlpha,
        width: 1
      },
      move: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 3,
        direction: "none",
        random: false,
        straight: false,
        out_mode: "out",
        bounce: false,
        attract: {
          enable: false,
          rotateX: 600,
          rotateY: 1200
        }
      }
    },
    interactivity: {
      detect_on: "canvas",
      events: {
        onhover: {
          enable: false,
          mode: "repulse"
        },
        onclick: {
          enable: false,
          mode: "push"
        },
        resize: true
      },
      modes: {
        grab: {
          distance: 400,
          line_linked: {
            opacity: 1
          }
        },
        bubble: {
          distance: 400,
          size: 40,
          duration: 2,
          opacity: 8,
          speed: 3
        },
        repulse: {
          distance: 200,
          duration: 0.4
        },
        push: {
          particles_nb: 4
        },
        remove: {
          particles_nb: 2
        }
      }
    },
    retina_detect: true
  });
}
```

If I can somehow store all this in a variable i.e. `particlescript` then i can provided it to jsZip to be added as a script file.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("script.js", particlescript);
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "project.zip");
});
```

Comment: Why can't you just store the script into a .js file (let's say `particleBG2.js`) and store this file in the zip..

Comment: user will be setting his own color & opacity i.e. the 2 parameters in my sample code above `particleColor, particleAlpha`

Comment: particlescript is a string right? So, instead of getting these variables as arguments to the function, just keep "placeholders" for them, let's say `{particleColor}` and `{particleAlpha}` and replace them after the user choose the colors.

Comment: placeholders how?

Comment: See it in my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the script content as string. Keep the variables as placeholders, and replace them in the values which the user entered.

Something like this:

```js
var template = `function particleBG2() {
  var particleColor = '{particleColor}';
  var particleAlpha = '{particleAlpha}';
  particlesJS("particles-js", {
    particles: {
      number: {
        value: 80,
        density: {
          enable: true,
          value_area: 800
        }
      },
      color: {
        value: particleColor
      },
      shape: {
        type: "circle",
        stroke: {
          width: 0
        },
        polygon: {
          nb_sides: 5
        },
        image: {
          src: "img/github.svg",
          width: 100,
          height: 100
        }
      },
      opacity: {
        value: particleAlpha,
        random: false,
        anim: {
          enable: false,
          speed: 1,
          opacity_min: 0.1,
          sync: false
        }
      },
      size: {
        value: 3,
        random: true,
        anim: {
          enable: false,
          speed: 40,
          size_min: 0.1,
          sync: false
        }
      },
      line_linked: {
        enable: true,
        distance: 150,
        color: particleColor,
        opacity: particleAlpha,
        width: 1
      },
      move: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 3,
        direction: "none",
        random: false,
        straight: false,
        out_mode: "out",
        bounce: false,
        attract: {
          enable: false,
          rotateX: 600,
          rotateY: 1200
        }
      }
    },
    interactivity: {
      detect_on: "canvas",
      events: {
        onhover: {
          enable: false,
          mode: "repulse"
        },
        onclick: {
          enable: false,
          mode: "push"
        },
        resize: true
      },
      modes: {
        grab: {
          distance: 400,
          line_linked: {
            opacity: 1
          }
        },
        bubble: {
          distance: 400,
          size: 40,
          duration: 2,
          opacity: 8,
          speed: 3
        },
        repulse: {
          distance: 200,
          duration: 0.4
        },
        push: {
          particles_nb: 4
        },
        remove: {
          particles_nb: 2
        }
      }
    },
    retina_detect: true
  });
}`;


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var particleAlpha = document.querySelector('#particleAlpha').value;
  var particleColor = document.querySelector('#particleColor').value;
  var particlescript = template.replace(/\{(.*)\}/g, function(a, b, c) {
    return eval(b);
  });
  console.log(particlescript);
  
  // var zip = new JSZip();
  // zip.file("script.js", particlescript);
  // zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
  //   saveAs(content, "project.zip");
  // });
});
```

```html
<input id="particleColor" type="text" placeholder="particleColor" value="#ddd" /><br />
<input id="particleAlpha" type="text" placeholder="particleAlpha" value="0.5" /><br />
<button>Save</button>
```